# My counting function is not working with the text on my lcd

Tags: programming, lcd

I want the bottom row of my LCD to display the counting function and include text:

```
lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
lcd.print("Launch in"millis()/1000);
```

But it comes out with an error, what part is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line in the code you provided won't compile.

The `lcd.print()` function expects a char, byte, int, long or string (taken from the LiquidCrystal docs) and you're trying to combine a string and an int which the compiler isn't going to understand.

The easiest way to print both would be to have two lcd.print statements:

```
lcd.print("launch in ");
lcd.print(millis()/1000);
```

Most of this is taken from quickly googling displaying time on an lcd screen.
Check out this forum post, it seems similar to what you want to do: [click me!](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,12003.0.html)

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line to:

```
lcd.print("Launch in " + (millis() / 1000));
```

The `+` *concatenates* the string `Launch in` with the number that results from `millis() / 1000`.

Answer (score 1):

```
lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
lcd.print("Launch in ");
lcd.print(millis()/1000);
```

Comment: Can you add why the original code didn't work? Answers are best if they have some explanation, not just code.